# Why is the symbol ∈ classified as a binary relation in first order set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, formal-languages

Aren't binary relations themselves defined using the symbol ∈ ? Also, what are the rules for writing down statements in first order set theory? If someone could point me towards a simple text, that'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: In the language of first-order set theory $\in$ is a constant being part of the language. It is a binary *predicate* symbols: the only primitive one (except *equality*, if the language is f-o with equality).

Comment: With the theroy havinf *sets* as objects of the domain of discourse, we define specific types of sets, like power-sets, relations and functions, that are all sets.

Comment: It defines a relationship between two objects, a 'variable' or a 'member' and the set, domain, or group with which it belongs. $a \in A$ needs to be defined using quantifiers, example: "for some $a$ in the set $A$, we have...*argumentation or expanded definition/statement*."

Comment: For introductory material, you can see: Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013) and Stephen Simpson, [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf) (2009).

Comment: There are two definitions of "binary relation" here. One is the intuitive one: A relationship between two thing, and is applied to primitive ideas in the *language* of a theory. Then there is the "internal" notion of a binary relation in set theory, which is a subset of a product set.  These are two different things, at heart, but they are very similar.

Comment: Note that, in (most?) set theory, there is no internal binary relation $R$ such that $\forall x,y(x\in y\iff (x,y)\in R)$. So the internal definition is, in some sense, "smaller" than the external definition.

Comment: It's worth thinking about a theory of "partially ordered sets." In that, you have just a few axioms: $(x\leq y\land y\leq x)\implies x=y$, $x\leq x$, and $(x\leq y\land y\leq z)\implies x\leq z$. There is no way to define "binary relation" inside this theory, but $\leq$ is still called a binary relation, because it describes the nature of the operation.

Comment: More generally, given any predicate $P(x,y)$ that has no unbound variables other than $x,y$, you have that $P(x,y)$ is an (external) binary relation. In this case, $P$ is not a primitive of the language. For example: $\forall z(z\in x\implies z\in y)$ defines the (external) binary relationship $\subseteq$, but it is not an "internal" relationship inside set theory.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with two essentially different uses of "binary relation."

1. The meaning that is applied to primitive binary predicates in **any** first order theory.
2. The definition, inside of the first order theory of sets, of a binary relation, as a subset of a product of two sets.

These are two different things, but they are closely related, semantically.

The first can be applied to any first order theory. For example, the first order theory of ordered fields has a binary relation, $\leq$, but that same theory has no "internal" notion of binary relation.

Also, the $\in$ binary relation has no internal representation as a binary relation (usually.) It is not necessarily true that $\exists R:\forall x,y\,(x\in y\iff (x,y)\in R$). That is $\in$ is not a binary relation of the type (2).

There is a third definition of "binary relation" which is an expansion of (1), namely "binary predicates:"

3. A binary relation is a predicate in a first order theory of the form $P(x,y)$ which has no other unbound variables.

For example, $\subseteq$ in the theory of sets is a binary relation of this sort, because it can be written as:

$$\forall z\,(z\in x\implies z\in y)$$

As with $\in$, this binary relation cannot be expressed internally as a binary relation of type (2).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! One follow up question I have is that how do we define it if it doesn't come under 1) or 2)?

Comment: Well, I did give example (3). It would all, in general, depend on the context. There aren't really examples in the field of set theory that isn't one of 1, 2, or 3. But outside of first order logics, not so sure. In Topos theory, you'd essentially have the same "internal" definition as in set theory.